# Is there an event in the Facebook JavaScript SDK that fires after a user has commented?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the following to display a coupon for users that have liked my company's page via a  Facebook 'Like' button on your page.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
// action
}
);
};
```

When a user clicks the 'Like' button the box appears asking if they want to post it to their wall with a message and the callback takes place at this time to display the coupon.

Is there a callback that occurs after the user has posted (or opted not to post)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this for posts then check the response:

```
<script>
function fb_share() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Name of App',
        link: 'http://YOURLINK.com',
        picture: 'someurltoimage.jpg',
        description: 'Your description of the post for the wall!'
        },
        function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            console.debug(response.post_id);
        // Post was published - now lets send it to our ouwn custom processing page on our server
        $.post('/process-post',{uid: <?php echo $currentUser; ?>, wallpost: response.post_id},function(resp) {
                // callback after storing the requests
            });
        } else {
        // Post was not published;
        }
    });
return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Briam.  I'll look into whether a similar format would work.  My hunch is that this would work to determine only that they posted, not that they had either posted or bypassed the posting step.

Oh well.  I think I've gotten as close as I can.  Thanks again!